# TL082 Voltage Follower

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

I just made a simple voltage follower using TL082. I applied 2.5V to voltage divider 100k and 25k, and apply that 500mV to positive input of TL082. But the output of follower is around supply voltage. The supply voltage is 5V-0V.

Do you have any idea about that?
[image]

Comment: Did you accidentally swap the + and - inputs?

Comment: If you are done with this Q and A session you should close it down by the normal method as explained in [this help page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Ivan, you need to understand that if you do want help, it is a 2 way process so, choose an answer that you find to be the most useful to you and formally accept it as per [this method](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: @ivanmateo please read and act on this --> [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and, if you need any help finding the answer accept button look at this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKrn6.png <-- after all, you don't want folk thinking your are mean-spirited in case the help they give you dwindles off.

Answer (score 3):

In case you run the TL082 on a single ended supply with negative supply at GND, the input of 0.5V could be below the acceptable level and cause a phase reversal. The datasheet states that the acceptable input common mode voltage is:
VCC- +2V to VCC+ +0.1V

If you cannot increase the supply range, look for more modern opamps. These can often work with inputs below the negative rail. If you need the output similarly close to the rail (as for a voltage follower), look into rail-to-rail opamps

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl082-n.pdf?ts=1616592058289&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) for the TL082 and see this table: -

[image]

In red, it's telling you that with a +/- 15 volt supply, the output voltage can typically only reach to within 1.5 volt of the negative power supply and, it can reach no closer than typically 1.5 volts to the positive supply rail. If your supply is 5 volts and 0 volts, then the output range is from +1.5 volts to +3.5 volts.

If you considered the worst case limit scenarios for output voltage it would be 3 volts above the negative rail to 3 volts below the positive rail (and clearly this is impossible with a single 5 volt power supply).

Similar story for the inputs (in blue).

So, the TL082 has a minimum supply voltage of +/- 5 volts (or 10 volts) and you do need to look into this problem: -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

0V as the negative supply will not work for inputs near 0V. 5V of supply voltage is also not enough.

It needs at least +5V and -5V for the supplies.